# jquery mobile - link listbox item with Store Object

Tags: jquery

I have a few pages in single HTML file. On one page I load a list from my WS (JSON) and I display them in `<li>`. 
How can I link list item with specific record in my data object ? There is no unique record ID btw.(tripId is not unique but tripID + custName is).
What I want to accomplish is to do 1 trip for data, display list with few details and then when user clicks on one item show full details about the record. I don't want to load it again - I think this way app will work faster in my scenario. Below code:

```
// Store object
var storeObject = {
    driverID: 0,
    tripID : 0,
    custName: '',
    City: '',
    state: '',
    zip: '',
    address1: '',
    phone: '',
    cell: '',
    contact: '',
    notes: '',
    APPT: '',
    done: '',
};
var uri = 'http://example.com/mywebservice.asmx/GetOpenTrips';
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#opentrips", function () {
    // Send an AJAX request
    $.getJSON(uri, { driverID: storeObject.driverID })
        .done(function (data) {
            // creating html string
            var listString = '<ul data-role="listview" id="tripsList">';
            console.log(data);

            // running a loop
            $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                listString += '<li><a href="#tripDetails?id=' + item.tripID + '" >' + '<h2>Trip# ' + item.tripID + '</h2><p>' +
                    item.descr + '</p><p>Miles: ' + item.miles + '</p></a></li>';
            });
            listString += '</ul>';

            //appending to the div
            $('#MyOpenTripsLists').html(listString);

            // refreshing the list to apply styles
            $('#MyOpenTripsLists ul').listview();

            $('#MyOpenTripsLists').on('click', 'li', function () {
                // alert("Works" + $(this).attr('id')); 
                console.log($(this).attr('id') + 'clicked...');
                // store all fields from data in store Object - how ?????????????????
                // I can store html ID like below but how to access other fields ?
                // I know data is accessible - console.log(data) and all records are listed
                storeObject.tripID = $(this).attr('id');
                storeObject.custName = ????????;
            });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be

1) Create a globally accessible variable:

```
var JSONData = null;
```

2) Then in your `.done()` function, set the value:

```
JSONData = data;
```

3) When you create your HTML string, add the `key` as a `data-` attribute:

```
listString += '<li data-key="' + key + '"><a href="#tripDetails?id=' + item.tripID + '" >' + 
    '<h2>Trip# ' + item.tripID + '</h2><p>' + item.descr + '</p><p>Miles: ' + item.miles + '</p></a></li>';
```

4) When the link is clicked, you can get access to the data object for the element like (assuming the click event is generated by the `a` tag):

```
var key = $(this).closest("li").data("key");
var dataObject = JSONData[key];
```

I see from the example that the click event is on the `li`, so:

```
var key = $(this).data("key");
var dataObject = JSONData[key];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I know I was missing something simple!

Comment: @AdamW I get twisted on JavaScript scoping sometimes, but I think that since your click event is being created inside the `done()` function, you actually don't have to create the global variable. I think you can use `data` in the click handler directly `var dataObject = data[key];`

Comment: both versions don't work. JSONData[key] -> JSONData is undefined; data[key] is giving me "undefined" value. var key=$(this).data("key") is returning correct data-key

Comment: You declared`var JSONData` outside the `done()` function? In the global scope? Then set the value in the `done()` function?

Comment: Sorry - my bad - I forgot to declare it first but now I'm getting "undefined" for dataObject on JSONData[key] - I can get single record using JSONDta[0] - looks like records are from 0 to 4 - key is a bigger number = 177. How to get an index number of clicked item ?

Comment: and You're right - I don't even need this global JSONData - same result for data[0]

Comment: Got it. I just had to generate key from 0 to [number of records] in $.each and then I can access the record using data[key]. Thanks again jwatts1980

Comment: @AdamW I am surprised that you had to generate a separate index. According to the jQuery docs, the `.each()` function passes the index and the item to the callback. So: `$.each(function(index, item){...`. Where you have the `key` parameter in the callback function, it's value _should_ be equal to the index already. I am curious as to why it didn't work.